# save and save as in Windows Form App by C#

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for making save as of image in c#

```
SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
        svf.Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";
        if (DialogResult.OK == svf.ShowDialog())
        {
            this.imgbox.Image.Save(svf.FileName,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

I need to make save now for image without change name or location ( apply save not save as as the above code ) how i can use this code for save now ?

Comment: If you already know the filename you don't show any SaveFile Dialog and save directly the image

Comment: Use a variable, don't forget the FileName.  It is not going to work btw, Image.Save() puts a lock on the file.  Use the Bitmap(Image) constructor to make a copy that you can dispose after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms, add a field or property to the appropriate control to hold the full path to the file currently opened, and call it `currentFileName` or something.

When opening a file, assign the path to the variable. Now when the user hits the Save menu, you can use the already stored path to overwrite the opened file. You can add a Save As menu that pops up the `SaveFileDialog`, and afterwards assigns the result to the variable again - if not cancelled.

When the user invokes the New or Close menu, make sure to clear the stored path.